# In a middleware, how can I get current logged in user?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I am creating a middleware that checks if user is currently logged in and is super admin.

This is my middleware code.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {

            // also need to check a field of user

            return redirect()->guest('login');
        } else {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, it's the same as the default middleware Authenticate (i.e. 'auth')

It's working well when I use it in app's routing. (app/Http/routes.php)

I need to use it with [cuddy plugin](https://github.com/cruddy/cruddy) middleware option. It should redirects only guest users, but it's not. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Authenticate middleware by default checks if user is guest and redirects him to login page see below

```
 if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401); //if ajax request
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login'); //redirect
        }
    }
```

Now if u want to check if user is logged and check some user fields here how it should be

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())  { //If is logged in
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->isSuperAdmin())
            return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/whatever');
}
```

> If you attach 'auth' middleware + this custom middleware. You can get rid of "Auth::check()" in the custom middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth', 'custom']], function () {
   Route::get('/url/only/for/super/users', 'Whatever@whateverController');
});

 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->isSuperAdmin())
            return $next($request);
    return redirect('/whatever');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many helper functions in laravel that you can use anywhere like auth() helper, [see helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-auth). So you can use this code anywhere:

```
auth()->user();
```